# Print out customer name, id, balance

Tags: java, class, object

I am writing a Java program that I need:

A method to read the customer names and id and store them in an array. (Read a sequence of zero or more lines each containing the name and id of one customer. Instantiate one `Customer` object per line and store each object in an array of objects. The array need not be more than 10 elements long. The sequence of `name` and `id` will end with an empty line).

### Main

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CustomerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer[] customers = new Customer[10];
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numItem;
        readCustomer(myScanner, customers); //not sure about this calling
        readNameAmount(myScanner, customers); ////not sure about this calling
    }
    public static void readCustomer(Scanner myScanner, Customer[] input) {
        boolean streamEnded = false;
        int numItem = 0;
        while (!streamEnded && myScanner.hasNext()) {
            String name = myScanner.nextLine();
            String id = myScanner.nextLine();
            if (name.length() == 0 && id.length() == 0) {
                streamEnded = true;
            } else {
                input[numItem] = name; //error
                input[numItem] = id; //error
            }
            numItem++;
            Customer customerTest = new Customer(name, id);
        }
    }
    public static void readNameAmount(Scanner myScanner, Customer[] input) {
        while (myScanner.hasNext()) {
            String id = myScanner.nextLine();
            double amount = myScanner.nextDouble();
            int i = 0;
            boolean found = false;
            while (i <numItem && !found) { //error
                if (customers[i].equals(id)) { //error
                    changeBalance(double value);//error
                }
                found = true;
                i++;
            }
        }
    } 
    public static void print(Customer[] input, int numItem) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numItem; i++) {
            System.out.println(customers[i].toString()); //error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Scope of `customers` and `numItem` is wrong (you probably need field here), and `changeBalance(double value)` is not a valid syntax, did you mean `changeBalance(amount);`

Comment: Are sure the input example is right? I mean you said that the "The sequence of name and id will end with an empty line" but there is an empty line after the first line and after the second, so an empty line doesn't determine if the sequence ended

Comment: add setters to customer class and call like this  input[numItem].setName(name);
input[numItem].setId(id); and numItems is not there in readNameAmount method and where is  changeBalance method ?

Comment: @Benj : In print method it should be like "    System.out.println(input[i].toString()); "

Comment: @maczikasz My bad, the input should be have an empty line before read the next line (id and amount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check if this works.
I dont know whether I understood your question.And I just cleared the error.

```
public class CustomerTest {
static int numItem = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customer[] customers = new Customer[10];
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    readCustomer(myScanner, customers); //not sure about this calling
    readNameAmount(myScanner, customers); ////not sure about this calling
}
public static void readCustomer(Scanner myScanner, Customer[] input) {
    boolean streamEnded = false;

    while (!streamEnded && myScanner.hasNext()) {
        String name = myScanner.nextLine();
        String id = myScanner.nextLine();
        if (name.length() == 0 && id.length() == 0) {
            streamEnded = true;
        } 
        else {
            input[numItem].getName();
            input[numItem].getId(); //error
        }
        numItem++;
        Customer customerTest = new Customer(name, id);
    }
}
public static void readNameAmount(Scanner myScanner, Customer[] input) {
    while (myScanner.hasNext()) {

        String id = myScanner.nextLine();
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        double amount = myScanner.nextDouble();
        int i = 0;
        boolean found = false;

        while (i < numItem && !found) { //error

            if (input[i].equals(id)) { //error
                cust.changeBalance(amount);//error
            }
            found = true;
            i++;
        }
    }
} 
public static void print(Customer[] input, int numItem) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numItem; i++) {

        System.out.println(input[i].toString()); //error
    }
}
}
```

Let me know your thoughts.

**Customer.java**

```
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private double balance;

    public Customer(){

    }
    public Customer(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void changeBalance(double value) {
        balance = balance + value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "name " + name + " id " + id + " balance " + balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got error on create object cust. Do i need a constructor for that?

Comment: @Benj: Yes you need a constructer.Pls see my edit.Is that working properly?